# .next('tag') in plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to search for the next sibling-element with a specified tag?

.nextElementSibling is not a function so... can't pass any tag with it?

jQuery

```
   $(event.target).parent().next('div').attr('id')
```

Java Script

```
  event.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.getAttribute('id');
```

Comment: Add a loop, check the `nodeName` and you're done

Answer (score 0):

you should try using querySelectorAll https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll

and then simply just looping over the results for your desired result. Please have a look at the following js fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/c0bdgxtj/12/

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
var debugEle = document.getElementById("debug");

var desiredElements = wrapper.querySelectorAll('div[data-test="y"]');
```